# Test Coherence Near Scheme

Tags: oracle, caching, oracle-coherence

I've set up a near scheme cache in Coherence with a local front scheme and remote back scheme.

I think the configuration is correct, but I want to be sure it's checking the front cache, before the back.

How can I test this? I'm using Windows.

My config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cache-config xmlns="http://schemas.tangosol.com/cache">
  <caching-scheme-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
      <cache-name>common-cache</cache-name>
      <scheme-name>near-cache</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
  </caching-scheme-mapping>
  <caching-schemes>
    <near-scheme>
      <scheme-name>near-cache</scheme-name>
      <invalidation-strategy>all</invalidation-strategy>
      <front-scheme>
        <local-scheme>
          <scheme-ref>local</scheme-ref>
        </local-scheme>
      </front-scheme>
      <back-scheme>
        <remote-cache-scheme>
          <scheme-ref>remote</scheme-ref>
        </remote-cache-scheme>
      </back-scheme>
    </near-scheme>
    <remote-cache-scheme>
      <scheme-name>remote</scheme-name>
      <service-name>ExtendTcpCacheService</service-name>
      <initiator-config>
        <tcp-initiator>
          <remote-addresses>
            <socket-address>
              <address>xxx.xxx.xxx.com</address>
              <port>555</port>
            </socket-address>
          </remote-addresses>
          <connect-timeout>5s</connect-timeout>
        </tcp-initiator>
        <outgoing-message-handler>
          <request-timeout>30s</request-timeout>
        </outgoing-message-handler>
        <serializer>
          <class-name>Tangosol.IO.Pof.ConfigurablePofContext, Coherence</class-name>
          <init-params>
            <init-param>
              <param-type>string</param-type>
              <param-value>web://~/coherence-pof-config.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
          </init-params>
        </serializer>
      </initiator-config>
    </remote-cache-scheme>
    <local-scheme>
      <scheme-name>local</scheme-name>
      <eviction-policy>HYBRID</eviction-policy>
      <high-units>1000</high-units>
      <low-units>750</low-units>
      <unit-calculator>FIXED</unit-calculator>
      <expiry-delay>10d</expiry-delay>
      <flush-delay>1d</flush-delay>
    </local-scheme>
  </caching-schemes>
</cache-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following:

set:

```
 <invalidation-strategy>None</invalidation-strategy>
```

*This strategy instructs the cache not to listen for invalidation events at all. This is the best choice for raw performance and scalability when business requirements permit the use of data which might not be absolutely current. Freshness of data can be guaranteed by use of a sufficiently brief eviction policy for the front cache*
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18677/cache_config.htm

- add entry to the cache
- update  entry from second client
- verify that first client has unmodified entry

Answer (score 0):

"common-cache" does use the "near-cache" scheme, so that is the behavior you are looking for.

To test it, access 100000 different (and non-existent) keys, e.g. new Integer(1) through new Integer(100000), and test the time. Now "put" a key in for Integer(1), e.g.

```
cache.put(new Integer(1), "hello world")
```

and then repeat the first test, but instead of accessing 1 through 100000, just access "new Integer(1)" repeatedly -- 100,000 times!

The first test might take a minute or two (depending on how many servers, are they on the same machine, etc.) The second test should take less than a second.